# How to transform regular svg file into svg tiny?

Tags: c++, qt, svg

I need to display graphs stored as svg files on a QGraphicsScene.

Normally, the way to do it is to use QtSVG (with QSvgRenderer and QGraphicsSvgItem). But those only implement svg tiny standards.

The graphs I need to display contains some texts using "symbol" elements (for axes labels), which are not part of svg tiny. So the image I get doesn't display the text. Any web browser I tried can display them fine, and so does inkscape, but not Qt.

So, the way I see it, I have two options: one is to rewrite/inherit from the QtSVG library to handle those format, which seems quite complex. The other would be to transform my svg file into another svg that fits the "tiny" standard.

Then I found this library (https://github.com/manisandro/svg2svgt) which allows to transform svg into svgt files. I thought it would do the trick. But sadly, it appears this transformation also drops those symbols, instead of transforming them into something that is part of svgt. So I'm back to square one.

An example of the type of svg files that I need to display:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="432pt"
height="432pt" viewBox="0 0 432 432" version="1.1"> <defs> <g> <symbol
overflow="visible" id="glyph0-0"> <path style="stroke:none;" d="M
0.519531 -4.414063 C 0.515625 -5.46875 0.625 -6.320313 0.84375 -6.964844 C 1.0625 -7.609375 1.386719 -8.105469 1.816406 -8.457031 C 2.246094 -8.804688 2.785156 -8.980469 3.4375 -8.984375 C 3.914063 -8.980469 4.335938 -8.886719 4.699219 -8.695313 C 5.058594 -8.5 5.355469 -8.21875 5.59375 -7.859375 C 5.828125 -7.492188 6.015625 -7.050781 6.152344 -6.527344 C 6.285156 -6.003906 6.351563 -5.296875 6.355469 -4.414063 C 6.351563 -3.359375 6.242188 -2.511719 6.03125 -1.871094 C 5.8125 -1.222656 5.492188 -0.726563 5.0625 -0.375 C 4.632813 -0.0234375 4.089844 0.152344 3.4375 0.152344 C 2.570313 0.152344 1.890625 -0.15625 1.402344 -0.773438 C 0.808594 -1.515625 0.515625 -2.726563 0.519531 -4.414063 Z M 1.648438 -4.414063 C 1.644531 -2.941406 1.816406 -1.964844 2.164063 -1.480469 C 2.503906 -0.992188 2.929688 -0.75 3.4375 -0.75 C 3.9375 -0.75 4.359375 -0.992188 4.707031 -1.480469 C 5.050781 -1.96875 5.226563 -2.945313 5.226563 -4.414063 C 5.226563 -5.882813 5.050781 -6.863281 4.707031 -7.347656 C 4.359375 -7.832031 3.933594 -8.074219 3.425781 -8.074219 C 2.917969 -8.074219 2.515625 -7.859375 2.214844 -7.433594 C 1.835938 -6.886719 1.644531 -5.878906 1.648438 -4.414063 Z M 1.648438 -4.414063 "/> </symbol> <symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph0-1"> <path
style="stroke:none;" d="M 1.136719 0 L 1.136719 -1.25 L 2.386719 -1.25
L 2.386719 0 Z M 1.136719 0 "/> </symbol> <symbol overflow="visible"
id="glyph0-2"> <path style="stroke:none;" d="M 6.21875 -6.757813 L
5.125 -6.671875 C 5.027344 -7.097656 4.890625 -7.410156 4.710938 -7.609375 C 4.414063 -7.921875 4.046875 -8.078125 3.613281 -8.082031 C 3.261719 -8.078125 2.953125 -7.980469 2.691406 -7.789063 C 2.339844 -7.53125 2.066406 -7.164063 1.871094 -6.683594 C 1.667969 -6.195313 1.566406 -5.503906 1.5625 -4.613281 C 1.824219 -5.011719 2.148438 -5.3125 2.53125 -5.511719 C 2.914063 -5.703125 3.3125 -5.800781 3.734375 -5.804688 C 4.464844 -5.800781 5.089844 -5.53125 5.605469 -4.996094 C 6.117188 -4.453125 6.375 -3.757813 6.378906 -2.90625 C 6.375 -2.34375 6.253906 -1.820313 6.015625 -1.339844 C 5.769531 -0.855469 5.4375 -0.484375 5.015625 -0.230469 C 4.59375 0.0273438 4.113281 0.152344 3.578125 0.152344 C 2.660156 0.152344 1.914063 -0.183594 1.335938 -0.855469 C 0.757813 -1.527344 0.46875 -2.636719 0.46875 -4.1875 C 0.46875 -5.914063 0.789063 -7.171875 1.429688 -7.960938 C 1.984375 -8.640625 2.734375 -8.980469 3.679688 -8.984375 C 4.382813 -8.980469 4.957031 -8.785156 5.410156 -8.390625 C 5.855469 -7.996094 6.125 -7.449219 6.21875 -6.757813 Z M 1.734375 -2.898438 C 1.734375 -2.519531 1.8125 -2.15625 1.972656 -1.8125 C 2.132813 -1.460938 2.359375 -1.199219 2.648438 -1.019531 C 2.9375 -0.839844 3.238281 -0.75 3.558594 -0.75 C 4.019531 -0.75 4.417969 -0.9375 4.753906 -1.3125 C 5.082031 -1.6875 5.25 -2.195313 5.253906 -2.839844 C 5.25 -3.453125 5.085938 -3.941406 4.757813 -4.300781 C 4.429688
-4.65625 4.015625 -4.832031 3.515625 -4.835938 C 3.015625 -4.832031 2.59375 -4.65625 2.25 -4.300781 C 1.90625 -3.941406 1.734375 -3.472656 1.734375 -2.898438 Z M 1.734375 -2.898438 "/> </symbol> <symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph0-3"> <path style="stroke:none;" d="M
2.210938 -4.851563 C 1.75 -5.015625 1.414063 -5.253906 1.195313 -5.566406 C 0.976563 -5.875 0.867188 -6.242188 0.867188 -6.675781 C 0.867188 -7.324219 1.097656 -7.871094 1.566406 -8.316406 C 2.03125 -8.757813 2.65625 -8.980469 3.4375 -8.984375 C 4.214844 -8.980469 4.84375 -8.753906 5.320313 -8.304688 C 5.796875 -7.847656 6.035156 -7.296875 6.035156 -6.648438 C 6.035156 -6.230469 5.925781 -5.867188 5.707031 -5.5625 C 5.488281 -5.25 5.15625 -5.015625 4.71875 -4.851563 C 5.265625 -4.671875 5.683594 -4.382813 5.972656 -3.984375 C 6.253906
-3.585938 6.398438 -3.109375 6.402344 -2.558594 C 6.398438 -1.789063 6.128906 -1.144531 5.589844 -0.628906 C 5.046875 -0.105469 4.332031 0.152344 3.453125 0.152344 C 2.566406 0.152344 1.855469 -0.105469 1.316406 -0.628906 C 0.773438 -1.148438 0.503906 -1.800781 0.507813 -2.585938 C 0.503906 -3.164063 0.652344 -3.652344 0.949219 -4.050781 C 1.242188 -4.441406 1.660156 -4.710938 2.210938 -4.851563 Z M 1.988281 -6.714844 C 1.984375 -6.289063 2.121094 -5.941406 2.398438 -5.675781 C 2.667969 -5.40625 3.023438 -5.273438 3.460938 -5.273438 C 3.878906 -5.273438 4.226563 -5.40625 4.5 -5.671875 C 4.769531 -5.9375 4.902344 -6.261719 4.90625 -6.652344 C 4.902344 -7.050781 4.765625 -7.390625 4.488281 -7.667969 C 4.207031 -7.941406 3.859375 -8.078125 3.449219 -8.082031 C 3.027344 -8.078125 2.679688 -7.945313 2.402344 -7.675781 C 2.125 -7.40625 1.984375 -7.085938 1.988281 -6.714844 Z M 1.636719 -2.582031 C 1.632813 -2.265625 1.707031 -1.960938 1.859375 -1.671875 C 2.003906 -1.375 2.226563 -1.148438 2.519531 -0.992188 C 2.8125 -0.828125 3.128906 -0.75 3.46875 -0.75 C 3.992188 -0.75 4.421875 -0.917969 4.765625 -1.257813 C 5.105469 -1.59375 5.277344 -2.023438 5.28125 -2.546875 C 5.277344 -3.074219 5.101563 -3.511719 4.75 -3.855469 C 4.394531 -4.199219 3.953125 -4.371094 3.429688 -4.375 C 2.910156 -4.371094 2.484375 -4.199219 2.144531 -3.863281 C 1.804688 -3.519531 1.632813 -3.09375 1.636719 -2.582031 Z M 1.636719 -2.582031 "/> </symbol> <symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph0-4"> <path
style="stroke:none;" d="M 4.65625 0 L 3.558594 0 L 3.558594 -7 C
3.289063 -6.746094 2.941406 -6.492188 2.515625 -6.242188 C 2.085938 -5.988281 1.703125 -5.800781 1.359375 -5.675781 L 1.359375 -6.738281 C 1.972656 -7.027344 2.507813 -7.375 2.972656 -7.789063 C 3.429688 -8.195313 3.757813 -8.59375 3.949219 -8.984375 L 4.65625 -8.984375 Z M 4.65625 0 "/> </symbol> <symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph0-5"> <path style="stroke:none;" d="M 6.292969 -1.054688 L 6.292969 0 L
0.378906 0 C 0.367188 -0.265625 0.410156 -0.519531 0.507813 -0.761719 C 0.65625 -1.164063 0.898438 -1.558594 1.230469 -1.953125 C 1.558594
-2.339844 2.035156 -2.792969 2.667969 -3.308594 C 3.636719 -4.101563 4.292969 -4.734375 4.636719 -5.203125 C 4.976563 -5.667969 5.148438 -6.105469 5.152344 -6.523438 C 5.148438 -6.957031 4.992188 -7.324219 4.683594 -7.625 C 4.371094 -7.921875 3.96875 -8.074219 3.46875 -8.074219 C 2.9375 -8.074219 2.511719 -7.914063 2.195313 -7.597656 C 1.878906 -7.277344 1.71875 -6.839844 1.714844 -6.28125 L 0.585938 -6.398438 C 0.664063 -7.238281 0.953125 -7.878906 1.457031 -8.320313 C 1.960938 -8.761719 2.640625 -8.980469 3.492188 -8.984375 C 4.347656 -8.980469 5.023438 -8.742188 5.527344 -8.269531 C 6.027344 -7.789063 6.28125 -7.199219 6.28125 -6.5 C 6.28125 -6.140625 6.207031 -5.789063 6.058594 -5.445313 C 5.910156 -5.09375 5.664063 -4.730469 5.328125 -4.351563 C 4.984375 -3.964844 4.421875 -3.441406 3.636719 -2.777344 C 2.976563 -2.222656 2.554688 -1.84375 2.367188 -1.648438 C 2.179688 -1.449219 2.023438 -1.253906 1.90625 -1.054688 Z M 6.292969 -1.054688 "/> </symbol> <symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph0-6"> <path
style="stroke:none;" d="M 4.039063 0 L 4.039063 -2.140625 L 0.160156
-2.140625 L 0.160156 -3.148438 L 4.242188 -8.949219 L 5.140625 -8.949219 L 5.140625 -3.148438 L 6.347656 -3.148438 L 6.347656 -2.140625 L 5.140625 -2.140625 L 5.140625 0 Z M 4.039063 -3.148438 L 4.039063 -7.183594 L 1.238281 -3.148438 Z M 4.039063 -3.148438 "/> </symbol> <symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph0-7"> <path
style="stroke:none;" d="M 1.164063 0 L 1.164063 -8.949219 L 2.351563
-8.949219 L 2.351563 0 Z M 1.164063 0 "/> </symbol> <symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph0-8"> <path style="stroke:none;" d="M
0.824219 0 L 0.824219 -6.480469 L 1.8125 -6.480469 L 1.8125 -5.558594 C 2.285156 -6.269531 2.972656 -6.625 3.875 -6.628906 C 4.261719 -6.625
4.621094 -6.554688 4.953125 -6.417969 C 5.277344 -6.273438 5.523438 -6.089844 5.6875 -5.863281 C 5.847656 -5.632813 5.960938 -5.363281 6.03125 -5.054688 C 6.066406 -4.847656 6.085938 -4.492188 6.089844 -3.984375 L 6.089844 0 L 4.992188 0 L 4.992188 -3.941406 C 4.992188 -4.386719 4.949219 -4.722656 4.863281 -4.945313 C 4.777344 -5.167969 4.625 -5.34375 4.40625 -5.476563 C 4.1875 -5.605469 3.933594 -5.671875 3.644531 -5.675781 C 3.175781 -5.671875 2.769531 -5.523438 2.429688 -5.230469 C 2.089844 -4.929688 1.921875 -4.367188 1.921875 -3.539063 L 1.921875 0 Z M 0.824219 0 "/> </symbol> <symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph0-9"> <path style="stroke:none;" d="M 5.03125 0 L 5.03125
-0.816406 C 4.617188 -0.171875 4.011719 0.144531 3.214844 0.148438 C 2.695313 0.144531 2.21875 0.0078125 1.789063 -0.277344 C 1.351563 -0.558594 1.015625 -0.957031 0.78125 -1.472656 C 0.539063 -1.980469 0.421875 -2.570313 0.425781 -3.234375 C 0.421875 -3.882813 0.53125 -4.46875 0.75 -4.996094 C 0.964844 -5.519531 1.285156 -5.921875 1.71875 -6.207031 C 2.148438 -6.484375 2.632813 -6.625 3.167969 -6.628906 C 3.554688 -6.625 3.902344 -6.542969 4.210938 -6.378906 C 4.511719 -6.210938 4.761719 -5.996094 4.957031 -5.738281 L 4.957031 -8.949219 L 6.046875 -8.949219 L 6.046875 0 Z M 1.554688 -3.234375 C 1.550781 -2.402344 1.726563 -1.78125 2.078125 -1.371094 C 2.425781 -0.960938 2.839844 -0.753906 3.320313 -0.757813 C 3.796875 -0.753906 4.203125 -0.949219 4.542969 -1.34375 C 4.875 -1.734375 5.042969 -2.335938 5.046875 -3.144531 C 5.042969 -4.027344 4.875 -4.675781 4.535156 -5.09375 C 4.191406 -5.507813 3.769531 -5.71875 3.273438 -5.71875 C 2.78125 -5.71875 2.371094 -5.519531 2.046875 -5.121094 C 1.714844 -4.722656 1.550781 -4.09375 1.554688 -3.234375 Z M 1.554688 -3.234375 "/> </symbol> <symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph0-10"> <path style="stroke:none;" d="M 5.261719 -2.085938 L 6.398438
-1.945313 C 6.21875 -1.28125 5.886719 -0.765625 5.402344 -0.402344 C 4.917969 -0.0351563 4.296875 0.144531 3.546875 0.148438 C 2.59375 0.144531 1.84375 -0.144531 1.289063 -0.726563 C 0.734375 -1.3125 0.457031 -2.132813 0.457031 -3.1875 C 0.457031 -4.273438 0.734375 -5.117188 1.296875 -5.722656 C 1.855469 -6.324219 2.585938 -6.625 3.484375 -6.628906 C 4.347656 -6.625 5.054688 -6.332031 5.609375 -5.742188 C 6.15625 -5.152344 6.433594 -4.320313 6.433594 -3.253906 C 6.433594 -3.183594 6.429688 -3.085938 6.425781 -2.960938 L 1.59375 -2.960938 C 1.632813 -2.242188 1.832031 -1.699219 2.195313 -1.324219 C 2.558594 -0.945313 3.011719 -0.753906 3.550781 -0.757813 C 3.953125 -0.753906 4.296875 -0.859375 4.582031 -1.074219 C 4.867188 -1.28125 5.09375 -1.621094 5.261719 -2.085938 Z M 1.652344 -3.863281 L 5.273438 -3.863281 C 5.222656 -4.402344 5.082031 -4.8125 4.859375 -5.089844 C 4.503906 -5.511719 4.050781 -5.722656 3.496094 -5.726563 C 2.992188 -5.722656 2.570313 -5.554688 2.226563 -5.21875 C 1.882813 -4.878906 1.691406 -4.425781 1.652344 -3.863281 Z M 1.652344 -3.863281 "/> </symbol> <symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph0-11"> <path
style="stroke:none;" d="M 0.0898438 0 L 2.460938 -3.367188 L 0.269531
-6.480469 L 1.640625 -6.480469 L 2.636719 -4.960938 C 2.824219 -4.667969 2.972656 -4.425781 3.089844 -4.234375 C 3.261719 -4.503906 3.425781 -4.742188 3.582031 -4.949219 L 4.675781 -6.480469 L 5.988281 -6.480469 L 3.746094 -3.429688 L 6.160156 0 L 4.808594 0 L 3.480469 -2.015625 L 3.125 -2.558594 L 1.421875 0 Z M 0.0898438 0 "/> </symbol> <symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph1-0"> <path style="stroke:none;"
d="M -4.414063 -0.519531 C -5.46875 -0.515625 -6.320313 -0.625
-6.964844 -0.84375 C -7.609375 -1.0625 -8.105469 -1.386719 -8.457031 -1.816406 C -8.804688 -2.246094 -8.980469 -2.785156 -8.984375 -3.4375 C -8.980469 -3.914063 -8.886719 -4.335938 -8.695313 -4.699219 C -8.5
-5.058594 -8.21875 -5.355469 -7.859375 -5.59375 C -7.492188 -5.828125 -7.050781 -6.015625 -6.527344 -6.152344 C -6.003906 -6.285156 -5.296875 -6.351563 -4.414063 -6.355469 C -3.359375 -6.351563 -2.511719 -6.242188 -1.871094 -6.03125 C -1.222656 -5.8125 -0.726563 -5.492188 -0.375 -5.0625 C -0.0234375 -4.632813 0.152344 -4.089844 0.152344 -3.4375 C 0.152344 -2.570313 -0.15625 -1.890625 -0.773438 -1.402344 C -1.515625 -0.808594 -2.726563 -0.515625 -4.414063 -0.519531 Z M -4.414063 -1.648438 C -2.941406 -1.644531 -1.964844 -1.816406 -1.480469 -2.164063 C -0.992188 -2.503906 -0.75 -2.929688 -0.75 -3.4375 C -0.75 -3.9375 -0.992188 -4.359375 -1.480469 -4.707031 C -1.96875 -5.050781 -2.945313 -5.226563 -4.414063 -5.226563 C
-5.882813 -5.226563 -6.863281 -5.050781 -7.347656 -4.707031 C -7.832031 -4.359375 -8.074219 -3.933594 -8.074219 -3.425781 C -8.074219 -2.917969 -7.859375 -2.515625 -7.433594 -2.214844 C -6.886719 -1.835938 -5.878906 -1.644531 -4.414063 -1.648438 Z M -4.414063 -1.648438 "/> </symbol> <symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph1-1"> <path style="stroke:none;" d="M 0 -1.136719 L -1.25
-1.136719 L -1.25 -2.386719 L 0 -2.386719 Z M 0 -1.136719 "/> </symbol> <symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph1-2"> <path
style="stroke:none;" d="M -6.757813 -6.21875 L -6.671875 -5.125 C
-7.097656 -5.027344 -7.410156 -4.890625 -7.609375 -4.710938 C -7.921875 -4.414063 -8.078125 -4.046875 -8.082031 -3.613281 C -8.078125 -3.261719 -7.980469 -2.953125 -7.789063 -2.691406 C -7.53125 -2.339844 -7.164063 -2.066406 -6.683594 -1.871094 C -6.195313 -1.667969 -5.503906 -1.566406 -4.613281 -1.5625 C -5.011719 -1.824219 -5.3125 -2.148438 -5.511719 -2.53125 C -5.703125 -2.914063 -5.800781 -3.3125 -5.804688 -3.734375 C -5.800781 -4.464844 -5.53125 -5.089844 -4.996094 -5.605469 C -4.453125 -6.117188 -3.757813 -6.375 -2.90625 -6.378906 C -2.34375 -6.375 -1.820313 -6.253906 -1.339844 -6.015625 C -0.855469 -5.769531 -0.484375 -5.4375 -0.230469 -5.015625 C 0.0273438 -4.59375 0.152344 -4.113281 0.152344 -3.578125 C 0.152344 -2.660156 -0.183594 -1.914063 -0.855469 -1.335938 C -1.527344 -0.757813 -2.636719 -0.46875 -4.1875 -0.46875 C -5.914063 -0.46875 -7.171875 -0.789063 -7.960938 -1.429688 C -8.640625 -1.984375 -8.980469 -2.734375 -8.984375 -3.679688 C -8.980469 -4.382813 -8.785156 -4.957031 -8.390625 -5.410156 C -7.996094 -5.855469 -7.449219 -6.125 -6.757813 -6.21875 Z M -2.898438 -1.734375 C -2.519531 -1.734375 -2.15625 -1.8125 -1.8125 -1.972656 C -1.460938 -2.132813 -1.199219 -2.359375 -1.019531 -2.648438 C -0.839844 -2.9375 -0.75 -3.238281 -0.75 -3.558594 C -0.75 -4.019531 -0.9375 -4.417969 -1.3125 -4.753906 C -1.6875 -5.082031 -2.195313 -5.25 -2.839844 -5.253906 C -3.453125
-5.25 -3.941406 -5.085938 -4.300781 -4.757813 C -4.65625 -4.429688 -4.832031 -4.015625 -4.835938 -3.515625 C -4.832031 -3.015625 -4.65625 -2.59375 -4.300781 -2.25 C -3.941406 -1.90625 -3.472656 -1.734375 -2.898438 -1.734375 Z M -2.898438 -1.734375 "/> </symbol> <symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph1-3"> <path style="stroke:none;" d="M
-4.851563 -2.210938 C -5.015625 -1.75 -5.253906 -1.414063 -5.566406 -1.195313 C -5.875 -0.976563 -6.242188 -0.867188 -6.675781 -0.867188 C -7.324219 -0.867188 -7.871094 -1.097656 -8.316406 -1.566406 C -8.757813 -2.03125 -8.980469 -2.65625 -8.984375 -3.4375 C -8.980469 -4.214844 -8.753906 -4.84375 -8.304688 -5.320313 C -7.847656 -5.796875 -7.296875 -6.035156 -6.648438 -6.035156 C -6.230469 -6.035156 -5.867188 -5.925781 -5.5625 -5.707031 C -5.25 -5.488281 -5.015625 -5.15625 -4.851563 -4.71875 C -4.671875 -5.265625 -4.382813 -5.683594 -3.984375 -5.972656 C -3.585938 -6.253906 -3.109375 -6.398438 -2.558594 -6.402344 C -1.789063 -6.398438 -1.144531 -6.128906 -0.628906 -5.589844 C -0.105469 -5.046875 0.152344 -4.332031 0.152344 -3.453125 C 0.152344 -2.566406 -0.105469 -1.855469 -0.628906 -1.316406 C -1.148438 -0.773438 -1.800781 -0.503906 -2.585938 -0.507813 C
-3.164063 -0.503906 -3.652344 -0.652344 -4.050781 -0.949219 C -4.441406 -1.242188 -4.710938 -1.660156 -4.851563 -2.210938 Z M -6.714844 -1.988281 C -6.289063 -1.984375 -5.941406 -2.121094 -5.675781 -2.398438 C -5.40625 -2.667969 -5.273438 -3.023438 -5.273438 -3.460938 C -5.273438 -3.878906 -5.40625 -4.226563 -5.671875 -4.5 C -5.9375 -4.769531 -6.261719 -4.902344 -6.652344 -4.90625 C -7.050781 -4.902344 -7.390625 -4.765625 -7.667969 -4.488281 C -7.941406 -4.207031 -8.078125 -3.859375 -8.082031 -3.449219 C -8.078125 -3.027344 -7.945313 -2.679688 -7.675781 -2.402344 C -7.40625 -2.125 -7.085938 -1.984375 -6.714844 -1.988281 Z M -2.582031 -1.636719 C -2.265625 -1.632813 -1.960938 -1.707031 -1.671875 -1.859375 C -1.375 -2.003906 -1.148438 -2.226563 -0.992188 -2.519531 C -0.828125 -2.8125 -0.75 -3.128906 -0.75 -3.46875 C -0.75 -3.992188 -0.917969 -4.421875 -1.257813 -4.765625 C -1.59375 -5.105469 -2.023438 -5.277344 -2.546875 -5.28125 C -3.074219 -5.277344 -3.511719 -5.101563 -3.855469 -4.75 C -4.199219 -4.394531 -4.371094 -3.953125 -4.375 -3.429688 C -4.371094 -2.910156 -4.199219 -2.484375 -3.863281 -2.144531 C -3.519531 -1.804688 -3.09375 -1.632813 -2.582031 -1.636719 Z M -2.582031 -1.636719 "/> </symbol> <symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph1-4"> <path style="stroke:none;" d="M 0 -4.65625 L 0 -3.558594 L -7
-3.558594 C -6.746094 -3.289063 -6.492188 -2.941406 -6.242188 -2.515625 C -5.988281 -2.085938 -5.800781 -1.703125 -5.675781 -1.359375 L -6.738281 -1.359375 C -7.027344 -1.972656 -7.375 -2.507813 -7.789063 -2.972656 C -8.195313 -3.429688 -8.59375 -3.757813 -8.984375 -3.949219 L -8.984375 -4.65625 Z M 0 -4.65625 "/> </symbol> <symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph1-5"> <path style="stroke:none;" d="M
-1.054688 -6.292969 L 0 -6.292969 L 0 -0.378906 C -0.265625 -0.367188 -0.519531 -0.410156 -0.761719 -0.507813 C -1.164063 -0.65625 -1.558594 -0.898438 -1.953125 -1.230469 C -2.339844 -1.558594 -2.792969 -2.035156 -3.308594 -2.667969 C -4.101563 -3.636719 -4.734375 -4.292969 -5.203125 -4.636719 C -5.667969 -4.976563 -6.105469 -5.148438 -6.523438 -5.152344 C -6.957031 -5.148438 -7.324219 -4.992188 -7.625 -4.683594 C -7.921875 -4.371094 -8.074219 -3.96875 -8.074219 -3.46875 C -8.074219 -2.9375 -7.914063 -2.511719 -7.597656 -2.195313 C -7.277344 -1.878906 -6.839844 -1.71875 -6.28125 -1.714844 L -6.398438 -0.585938 C -7.238281 -0.664063 -7.878906 -0.953125
-8.320313 -1.457031 C -8.761719 -1.960938 -8.980469 -2.640625 -8.984375 -3.492188 C -8.980469 -4.347656 -8.742188 -5.023438 -8.269531 -5.527344 C -7.789063 -6.027344 -7.199219 -6.28125 -6.5 -6.28125 C -6.140625 -6.28125 -5.789063 -6.207031 -5.445313 -6.058594 C -5.09375 -5.910156 -4.730469 -5.664063 -4.351563 -5.328125 C
-3.964844 -4.984375 -3.441406 -4.421875 -2.777344 -3.636719 C -2.222656 -2.976563 -1.84375 -2.554688 -1.648438 -2.367188 C -1.449219 -2.179688 -1.253906 -2.023438 -1.054688 -1.90625 Z M -1.054688 -6.292969 "/> </symbol> <symbol overflow="visible" id="glyph1-6"> <path style="stroke:none;" d="M 0 -4.039063 L -2.140625 -4.039063 L
-2.140625 -0.160156 L -3.148438 -0.160156 L -8.949219 -4.242188 L -8.949219 -5.140625 L -3.148438 -5.140625 L -3.148438 -6.347656 L -2.140625 -6.347656 L -2.140625 -5.140625 L 0 -5.140625 Z M -3.148438 -4.039063 L -7.183594 -4.039063 L -3.148438 -1.238281 Z M -3.148438 -4.039063 "/> </symbol> </g> <clipPath id="clip1">   <path d="M 59.039063 59.039063 L 402.757813 59.039063 L 402.757813 359.558594 L 59.039063 359.558594 Z M 59.039063 59.039063 "/> </clipPath> <clipPath id="clip2">   <path d="M 59.039063 59.039063 L 402.757813 59.039063 L
402.757813 359.558594 L 59.039063 359.558594 Z M 59.039063 59.039063 "/> </clipPath> </defs> <g id="surface34"> <g clip-path="url(#clip1)"
clip-rule="nonzero"> <path
style="fill:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke:rgb(0%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:10;"
d="M 233.601563 208.800781 C 233.601563 213.066406 227.199219
213.066406 227.199219 208.800781 C 227.199219 204.535156 233.601563 204.535156 233.601563 208.800781 "/> </g> <path style="fill:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke:rgb(0%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:10;"
d="M 71.734375 358.558594 L 389.066406 358.558594 "/> <path
style="fill:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke:rgb(0%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:10;"
d="M 71.734375 358.558594 L 71.734375 365.761719 "/> <path
style="fill:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke:rgb(0%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:10;"
d="M 151.066406 358.558594 L 151.066406 365.761719 "/> <path
style="fill:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke:rgb(0%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:10;"
d="M 230.398438 358.558594 L 230.398438 365.761719 "/> <path
style="fill:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke:rgb(0%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:10;"
d="M 309.734375 358.558594 L 309.734375 365.761719 "/> <path
style="fill:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke:rgb(0%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:10;"
d="M 389.066406 358.558594 L 389.066406 365.761719 "/> <g
style="fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;">   <use
xlink:href="#glyph0-0" x="63.046875" y="385.921875"/>   <use
xlink:href="#glyph0-1" x="69.998779" y="385.921875"/>   <use
xlink:href="#glyph0-2" x="73.47168" y="385.921875"/> </g> <g
style="fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;">   <use
xlink:href="#glyph0-0" x="142.378906" y="385.921875"/>   <use
xlink:href="#glyph0-1" x="149.330811" y="385.921875"/>   <use
xlink:href="#glyph0-3" x="152.803711" y="385.921875"/> </g> <g
style="fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;">   <use
xlink:href="#glyph0-4" x="221.710938" y="385.921875"/>   <use
xlink:href="#glyph0-1" x="228.662842" y="385.921875"/>   <use
xlink:href="#glyph0-0" x="232.135742" y="385.921875"/> </g> <g
style="fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;">   <use
xlink:href="#glyph0-4" x="301.046875" y="385.921875"/>   <use
xlink:href="#glyph0-1" x="307.998779" y="385.921875"/>   <use
xlink:href="#glyph0-5" x="311.47168" y="385.921875"/> </g> <g
style="fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;">   <use
xlink:href="#glyph0-4" x="380.378906" y="385.921875"/>   <use
xlink:href="#glyph0-1" x="387.330811" y="385.921875"/>   <use
xlink:href="#glyph0-6" x="390.803711" y="385.921875"/> </g> <path
style="fill:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke:rgb(0%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:10;"
d="M 59.039063 347.464844 L 59.039063 70.132813 "/> <path
style="fill:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke:rgb(0%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:10;"
d="M 59.039063 347.464844 L 51.839844 347.464844 "/> <path
style="fill:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke:rgb(0%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:10;"
d="M 59.039063 278.132813 L 51.839844 278.132813 "/> <path
style="fill:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke:rgb(0%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:10;"
d="M 59.039063 208.800781 L 51.839844 208.800781 "/> <path
style="fill:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke:rgb(0%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:10;"
d="M 59.039063 139.464844 L 51.839844 139.464844 "/> <path
style="fill:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke:rgb(0%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:10;"
d="M 59.039063 70.132813 L 51.839844 70.132813 "/> <g
style="fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;">   <use
xlink:href="#glyph1-0" x="43.199219" y="356.152344"/>   <use
xlink:href="#glyph1-1" x="43.199219" y="349.200439"/>   <use
xlink:href="#glyph1-2" x="43.199219" y="345.727539"/> </g> <g
style="fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;">   <use
xlink:href="#glyph1-0" x="43.199219" y="286.820313"/>   <use
xlink:href="#glyph1-1" x="43.199219" y="279.868408"/>   <use
xlink:href="#glyph1-3" x="43.199219" y="276.395508"/> </g> <g
style="fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;">   <use
xlink:href="#glyph1-4" x="43.199219" y="217.488281"/>   <use
xlink:href="#glyph1-1" x="43.199219" y="210.536377"/>   <use
xlink:href="#glyph1-0" x="43.199219" y="207.063477"/> </g> <g
style="fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;">   <use
xlink:href="#glyph1-4" x="43.199219" y="148.152344"/>   <use
xlink:href="#glyph1-1" x="43.199219" y="141.200439"/>   <use
xlink:href="#glyph1-5" x="43.199219" y="137.727539"/> </g> <g
style="fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;">   <use
xlink:href="#glyph1-4" x="43.199219" y="78.820313"/>   <use
xlink:href="#glyph1-1" x="43.199219" y="71.868408"/>   <use
xlink:href="#glyph1-6" x="43.199219" y="68.395508"/> </g> <path
style="fill:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke:rgb(0%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:10;"
d="M 59.039063 358.558594 L 401.761719 358.558594 L 401.761719
59.039063 L 59.039063 59.039063 L 59.039063 358.558594 "/> <g style="fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;">   <use
xlink:href="#glyph0-7" x="215.109375" y="414.71875"/>   <use
xlink:href="#glyph0-8" x="218.582275" y="414.71875"/>   <use
xlink:href="#glyph0-9" x="225.53418" y="414.71875"/>   <use
xlink:href="#glyph0-10" x="232.486084" y="414.71875"/>   <use
xlink:href="#glyph0-11" x="239.437988" y="414.71875"/> </g> <g
style="fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;">   <use
xlink:href="#glyph1-4" x="14.398438" y="212.277344"/> </g> <g
clip-path="url(#clip2)" clip-rule="nonzero"> <path
style="fill:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke:rgb(0%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:0.0117647;stroke-miterlimit:10;"
d="M 59.039063 358.558594 L 93.3125 328.609375 "/> <path
style="fill:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke:rgb(100%,100%,100%);stroke-opacity:0.0117647;stroke-miterlimit:10;"
d="M 59.039063 358.558594 L 93.3125 328.609375 "/> </g> </g> </svg>
```

Does anyone know of a library that transforms svg files into svg files fitting the "tiny" standard ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a quite simple solution to “repair” the SVG file for QSvg:

I did it in the text editor (Notepad++) – replacing `symbol` by `g`.

Afterwards I got this file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="432pt"
 height="432pt" viewBox="0 0 432 432" version="1.1">
<defs>
<g>
<g overflow="visible" id="glyph0-0">
<path style="stroke:none;" d="M
 0.519531 -4.414063 C 0.515625 -5.46875 0.625 -6.320313 0.84375 -6.964844 C 1.0625 -7.609375 1.386719 -8.105469 1.816406 -8.457031 C 2.246094 -8.804688 2.785156 -8.980469 3.4375 -8.984375 C 3.914063 -8.980469 4.335938 -8.886719 4.699219 -8.695313 C 5.058594 -8.5 5.355469 -8.21875 5.59375 -7.859375 C 5.828125 -7.492188 6.015625 -7.050781 6.152344 -6.527344 C 6.285156 -6.003906 6.351563 -5.296875 6.355469 -4.414063 C 6.351563 -3.359375 6.242188 -2.511719 6.03125 -1.871094 C 5.8125 -1.222656 5.492188 -0.726563 5.0625 -0.375 C 4.632813 -0.0234375 4.089844 0.152344 3.4375 0.152344 C 2.570313 0.152344 1.890625 -0.15625 1.402344 -0.773438 C 0.808594 -1.515625 0.515625 -2.726563 0.519531 -4.414063 Z M 1.648438 -4.414063 C 1.644531 -2.941406 1.816406 -1.964844 2.164063 -1.480469 C 2.503906 -0.992188 2.929688 -0.75 3.4375 -0.75 C 3.9375 -0.75 4.359375 -0.992188 4.707031 -1.480469 C 5.050781 -1.96875 5.226563 -2.945313 5.226563 -4.414063 C 5.226563 -5.882813 5.050781 -6.863281 4.707031 -7.347656 C 4.359375 -7.832031 3.933594 -8.074219 3.425781 -8.074219 C 2.917969 -8.074219 2.515625 -7.859375 2.214844 -7.433594 C 1.835938 -6.886719 1.644531 -5.878906 1.648438 -4.414063 Z M 1.648438 -4.414063 "/></g>
<g overflow="visible" id="glyph0-1">
<path style="stroke:none;" d="M 1.136719 0 L 1.136719 -1.25 L 2.386719 -1.25
 L 2.386719 0 Z M 1.136719 0 "/>
</g>
<g overflow="visible" id="glyph0-2">
<path style="stroke:none;" d="M 6.21875 -6.757813 L 5.125 -6.671875 C 5.027344 -7.097656 4.890625 -7.410156 4.710938 -7.609375 C 4.414063 -7.921875 4.046875 -8.078125 3.613281 -8.082031 C 3.261719 -8.078125 2.953125 -7.980469 2.691406 -7.789063 C 2.339844 -7.53125 2.066406 -7.164063 1.871094 -6.683594 C 1.667969 -6.195313 1.566406 -5.503906 1.5625 -4.613281 C 1.824219 -5.011719 2.148438 -5.3125 2.53125 -5.511719 C 2.914063 -5.703125 3.3125 -5.800781 3.734375 -5.804688 C 4.464844 -5.800781 5.089844 -5.53125 5.605469 -4.996094 C 6.117188 -4.453125 6.375 -3.757813 6.378906 -2.90625 C 6.375 -2.34375 6.253906 -1.820313 6.015625 -1.339844 C 5.769531 -0.855469 5.4375 -0.484375 5.015625 -0.230469 C 4.59375 0.0273438 4.113281 0.152344 3.578125 0.152344 C 2.660156 0.152344 1.914063 -0.183594 1.335938 -0.855469 C 0.757813 -1.527344 0.46875 -2.636719 0.46875 -4.1875 C 0.46875 -5.914063 0.789063 -7.171875 1.429688 -7.960938 C 1.984375 -8.640625 2.734375 -8.980469 3.679688 -8.984375 C 4.382813 -8.980469 4.957031 -8.785156 5.410156 -8.390625 C 5.855469 -7.996094 6.125 -7.449219 6.21875 -6.757813 Z M 1.734375 -2.898438 C 1.734375 -2.519531 1.8125 -2.15625 1.972656 -1.8125 C 2.132813 -1.460938 2.359375 -1.199219 2.648438 -1.019531 C 2.9375 -0.839844 3.238281 -0.75 3.558594 -0.75 C 4.019531 -0.75 4.417969 -0.9375 4.753906 -1.3125 C 5.082031 -1.6875 5.25 -2.195313 5.253906 -2.839844 C 5.25 -3.453125 5.085938 -3.941406 4.757813 -4.300781 C 4.429688 -4.65625 4.015625 -4.832031 3.515625 -4.835938 C 3.015625 -4.832031 2.59375 -4.65625 2.25 -4.300781 C 1.90625 -3.941406 1.734375 -3.472656 1.734375 -2.898438 Z M 1.734375 -2.898438 "/>
</g>
<g overflow="visible" id="glyph0-3">
<path style="stroke:none;" d="M 2.210938 -4.851563 C 1.75 -5.015625 1.414063 -5.253906 1.195313 -5.566406 C 0.976563 -5.875 0.867188 -6.242188 0.867188 -6.675781 C 0.867188 -7.324219 1.097656 -7.871094 1.566406 -8.316406 C 2.03125 -8.757813 2.65625 -8.980469 3.4375 -8.984375 C 4.214844 -8.980469 4.84375 -8.753906 5.320313 -8.304688 C 5.796875 -7.847656 6.035156 -7.296875 6.035156 -6.648438 C 6.035156 -6.230469 5.925781 -5.867188 5.707031 -5.5625 C 5.488281 -5.25 5.15625 -5.015625 4.71875 -4.851563 C 5.265625 -4.671875 5.683594 -4.382813 5.972656 -3.984375 C 6.253906 -3.585938 6.398438 -3.109375 6.402344 -2.558594 C 6.398438 -1.789063 6.128906 -1.144531 5.589844 -0.628906 C 5.046875 -0.105469 4.332031 0.152344 3.453125 0.152344 C 2.566406 0.152344 1.855469 -0.105469 1.316406 -0.628906 C 0.773438 -1.148438 0.503906 -1.800781 0.507813 -2.585938 C 0.503906 -3.164063 0.652344 -3.652344 0.949219 -4.050781 C 1.242188 -4.441406 1.660156 -4.710938 2.210938 -4.851563 Z M 1.988281 -6.714844 C 1.984375 -6.289063 2.121094 -5.941406 2.398438 -5.675781 C 2.667969 -5.40625 3.023438 -5.273438 3.460938 -5.273438 C 3.878906 -5.273438 4.226563 -5.40625 4.5 -5.671875 C 4.769531 -5.9375 4.902344 -6.261719 4.90625 -6.652344 C 4.902344 -7.050781 4.765625 -7.390625 4.488281 -7.667969 C 4.207031 -7.941406 3.859375 -8.078125 3.449219 -8.082031 C 3.027344 -8.078125 2.679688 -7.945313 2.402344 -7.675781 C 2.125 -7.40625 1.984375 -7.085938 1.988281 -6.714844 Z M 1.636719 -2.582031 C 1.632813 -2.265625 1.707031 -1.960938 1.859375 -1.671875 C 2.003906 -1.375 2.226563 -1.148438 2.519531 -0.992188 C 2.8125 -0.828125 3.128906 -0.75 3.46875 -0.75 C 3.992188 -0.75 4.421875 -0.917969 4.765625 -1.257813 C 5.105469 -1.59375 5.277344 -2.023438 5.28125 -2.546875 C 5.277344 -3.074219 5.101563 -3.511719 4.75 -3.855469 C 4.394531 -4.199219 3.953125 -4.371094 3.429688 -4.375 C 2.910156 -4.371094 2.484375 -4.199219 2.144531 -3.863281 C 1.804688 -3.519531 1.632813 -3.09375 1.636719 -2.582031 Z M 1.636719 -2.582031 "/>
</g>
<g overflow="visible" id="glyph0-4">
<path
style="stroke:none;" d="M 4.65625 0 L 3.558594 0 L 3.558594 -7 C 3.289063 -6.746094 2.941406 -6.492188 2.515625 -6.242188 C 2.085938 -5.988281 1.703125 -5.800781 1.359375 -5.675781 L 1.359375 -6.738281 C 1.972656 -7.027344 2.507813 -7.375 2.972656 -7.789063 C 3.429688 -8.195313 3.757813 -8.59375 3.949219 -8.984375 L 4.65625 -8.984375 Z M 4.65625 0 "/>
</g>
<g overflow="visible" id="glyph0-5">
<path style="stroke:none;" d="M 6.292969 -1.054688 L 6.292969 0 L 0.378906 0 C 0.367188 -0.265625 0.410156 -0.519531 0.507813 -0.761719 C 0.65625 -1.164063 0.898438 -1.558594 1.230469 -1.953125 C 1.558594 -2.339844 2.035156 -2.792969 2.667969 -3.308594 C 3.636719 -4.101563 4.292969 -4.734375 4.636719 -5.203125 C 4.976563 -5.667969 5.148438 -6.105469 5.152344 -6.523438 C 5.148438 -6.957031 4.992188 -7.324219 4.683594 -7.625 C 4.371094 -7.921875 3.96875 -8.074219 3.46875 -8.074219 C 2.9375 -8.074219 2.511719 -7.914063 2.195313 -7.597656 C 1.878906 -7.277344 1.71875 -6.839844 1.714844 -6.28125 L 0.585938 -6.398438 C 0.664063 -7.238281 0.953125 -7.878906 1.457031 -8.320313 C 1.960938 -8.761719 2.640625 -8.980469 3.492188 -8.984375 C 4.347656 -8.980469 5.023438 -8.742188 5.527344 -8.269531 C 6.027344 -7.789063 6.28125 -7.199219 6.28125 -6.5 C 6.28125 -6.140625 6.207031 -5.789063 6.058594 -5.445313 C 5.910156 -5.09375 5.664063 -4.730469 5.328125 -4.351563 C 4.984375 -3.964844 4.421875 -3.441406 3.636719 -2.777344 C 2.976563 -2.222656 2.554688 -1.84375 2.367188 -1.648438 C 2.179688 -1.449219 2.023438 -1.253906 1.90625 -1.054688 Z M 6.292969 -1.054688 "/>
</g>
<g overflow="visible" id="glyph0-6">
<path style="stroke:none;" d="M 4.039063 0 L 4.039063 -2.140625 L 0.160156 -2.140625 L 0.160156 -3.148438 L 4.242188 -8.949219 L 5.140625 -8.949219 L 5.140625 -3.148438 L 6.347656 -3.148438 L 6.347656 -2.140625 L 5.140625 -2.140625 L 5.140625 0 Z M 4.039063 -3.148438 L 4.039063 -7.183594 L 1.238281 -3.148438 Z M 4.039063 -3.148438 "/>
</g>
<g overflow="visible" id="glyph0-7">
<path style="stroke:none;" d="M 1.164063 0 L 1.164063 -8.949219 L 2.351563 -8.949219 L 2.351563 0 Z M 1.164063 0 "/>
</g>
<g overflow="visible" id="glyph0-8">
<path style="stroke:none;" d="M 0.824219 0 L 0.824219 -6.480469 L 1.8125 -6.480469 L 1.8125 -5.558594 C 2.285156 -6.269531 2.972656 -6.625 3.875 -6.628906 C 4.261719 -6.625 4.621094 -6.554688 4.953125 -6.417969 C 5.277344 -6.273438 5.523438 -6.089844 5.6875 -5.863281 C 5.847656 -5.632813 5.960938 -5.363281 6.03125 -5.054688 C 6.066406 -4.847656 6.085938 -4.492188 6.089844 -3.984375 L 6.089844 0 L 4.992188 0 L 4.992188 -3.941406 C 4.992188 -4.386719 4.949219 -4.722656 4.863281 -4.945313 C 4.777344 -5.167969 4.625 -5.34375 4.40625 -5.476563 C 4.1875 -5.605469 3.933594 -5.671875 3.644531 -5.675781 C 3.175781 -5.671875 2.769531 -5.523438 2.429688 -5.230469 C 2.089844 -4.929688 1.921875 -4.367188 1.921875 -3.539063 L 1.921875 0 Z M 0.824219 0 "/>
</g>
<g overflow="visible" id="glyph0-9">
<path style="stroke:none;" d="M 5.03125 0 L 5.03125 -0.816406 C 4.617188 -0.171875 4.011719 0.144531 3.214844 0.148438 C 2.695313 0.144531 2.21875 0.0078125 1.789063 -0.277344 C 1.351563 -0.558594 1.015625 -0.957031 0.78125 -1.472656 C 0.539063 -1.980469 0.421875 -2.570313 0.425781 -3.234375 C 0.421875 -3.882813 0.53125 -4.46875 0.75 -4.996094 C 0.964844 -5.519531 1.285156 -5.921875 1.71875 -6.207031 C 2.148438 -6.484375 2.632813 -6.625 3.167969 -6.628906 C 3.554688 -6.625 3.902344 -6.542969 4.210938 -6.378906 C 4.511719 -6.210938 4.761719 -5.996094 4.957031 -5.738281 L 4.957031 -8.949219 L 6.046875 -8.949219 L 6.046875 0 Z M 1.554688 -3.234375 C 1.550781 -2.402344 1.726563 -1.78125 2.078125 -1.371094 C 2.425781 -0.960938 2.839844 -0.753906 3.320313 -0.757813 C 3.796875 -0.753906 4.203125 -0.949219 4.542969 -1.34375 C 4.875 -1.734375 5.042969 -2.335938 5.046875 -3.144531 C 5.042969 -4.027344 4.875 -4.675781 4.535156 -5.09375 C 4.191406 -5.507813 3.769531 -5.71875 3.273438 -5.71875 C 2.78125 -5.71875 2.371094 -5.519531 2.046875 -5.121094 C 1.714844 -4.722656 1.550781 -4.09375 1.554688 -3.234375 Z M 1.554688 -3.234375 "/>
</g>
<g overflow="visible" id="glyph0-10">
<path style="stroke:none;" d="M 5.261719 -2.085938 L 6.398438 -1.945313 C 6.21875 -1.28125 5.886719 -0.765625 5.402344 -0.402344 C 4.917969 -0.0351563 4.296875 0.144531 3.546875 0.148438 C 2.59375 0.144531 1.84375 -0.144531 1.289063 -0.726563 C 0.734375 -1.3125 0.457031 -2.132813 0.457031 -3.1875 C 0.457031 -4.273438 0.734375 -5.117188 1.296875 -5.722656 C 1.855469 -6.324219 2.585938 -6.625 3.484375 -6.628906 C 4.347656 -6.625 5.054688 -6.332031 5.609375 -5.742188 C 6.15625 -5.152344 6.433594 -4.320313 6.433594 -3.253906 C 6.433594 -3.183594 6.429688 -3.085938 6.425781 -2.960938 L 1.59375 -2.960938 C 1.632813 -2.242188 1.832031 -1.699219 2.195313 -1.324219 C 2.558594 -0.945313 3.011719 -0.753906 3.550781 -0.757813 C 3.953125 -0.753906 4.296875 -0.859375 4.582031 -1.074219 C 4.867188 -1.28125 5.09375 -1.621094 5.261719 -2.085938 Z M 1.652344 -3.863281 L 5.273438 -3.863281 C 5.222656 -4.402344 5.082031 -4.8125 4.859375 -5.089844 C 4.503906 -5.511719 4.050781 -5.722656 3.496094 -5.726563 C 2.992188 -5.722656 2.570313 -5.554688 2.226563 -5.21875 C 1.882813 -4.878906 1.691406 -4.425781 1.652344 -3.863281 Z M 1.652344 -3.863281 "/>
</g>
<g overflow="visible" id="glyph0-11">
<path style="stroke:none;" d="M 0.0898438 0 L 2.460938 -3.367188 L 0.269531 -6.480469 L 1.640625 -6.480469 L 2.636719 -4.960938 C 2.824219 -4.667969 2.972656 -4.425781 3.089844 -4.234375 C 3.261719 -4.503906 3.425781 -4.742188 3.582031 -4.949219 L 4.675781 -6.480469 L 5.988281 -6.480469 L 3.746094 -3.429688 L 6.160156 0 L 4.808594 0 L 3.480469 -2.015625 L 3.125 -2.558594 L 1.421875 0 Z M 0.0898438 0 "/>
</g>
<g overflow="visible" id="glyph1-0">
<path style="stroke:none;" d="M -4.414063 -0.519531 C -5.46875 -0.515625 -6.320313 -0.625 -6.964844 -0.84375 C -7.609375 -1.0625 -8.105469 -1.386719 -8.457031 -1.816406 C -8.804688 -2.246094 -8.980469 -2.785156 -8.984375 -3.4375 C -8.980469 -3.914063 -8.886719 -4.335938 -8.695313 -4.699219 C -8.5 -5.058594 -8.21875 -5.355469 -7.859375 -5.59375 C -7.492188 -5.828125 -7.050781 -6.015625 -6.527344 -6.152344 C -6.003906 -6.285156 -5.296875 -6.351563 -4.414063 -6.355469 C -3.359375 -6.351563 -2.511719 -6.242188 -1.871094 -6.03125 C -1.222656 -5.8125 -0.726563 -5.492188 -0.375 -5.0625 C -0.0234375 -4.632813 0.152344 -4.089844 0.152344 -3.4375 C 0.152344 -2.570313 -0.15625 -1.890625 -0.773438 -1.402344 C -1.515625 -0.808594 -2.726563 -0.515625 -4.414063 -0.519531 Z M -4.414063 -1.648438 C -2.941406 -1.644531 -1.964844 -1.816406 -1.480469 -2.164063 C -0.992188 -2.503906 -0.75 -2.929688 -0.75 -3.4375 C -0.75 -3.9375 -0.992188 -4.359375 -1.480469 -4.707031 C -1.96875 -5.050781 -2.945313 -5.226563 -4.414063 -5.226563 C -5.882813 -5.226563 -6.863281 -5.050781 -7.347656 -4.707031 C -7.832031 -4.359375 -8.074219 -3.933594 -8.074219 -3.425781 C -8.074219 -2.917969 -7.859375 -2.515625 -7.433594 -2.214844 C -6.886719 -1.835938 -5.878906 -1.644531 -4.414063 -1.648438 Z M -4.414063 -1.648438 "/>
</g>
<g overflow="visible" id="glyph1-1">
<path style="stroke:none;" d="M 0 -1.136719 L -1.25 -1.136719 L -1.25 -2.386719 L 0 -2.386719 Z M 0 -1.136719 "/> </g>
<g overflow="visible" id="glyph1-2">
<path style="stroke:none;" d="M -6.757813 -6.21875 L -6.671875 -5.125 C -7.097656 -5.027344 -7.410156 -4.890625 -7.609375 -4.710938 C -7.921875 -4.414063 -8.078125 -4.046875 -8.082031 -3.613281 C -8.078125 -3.261719 -7.980469 -2.953125 -7.789063 -2.691406 C -7.53125 -2.339844 -7.164063 -2.066406 -6.683594 -1.871094 C -6.195313 -1.667969 -5.503906 -1.566406 -4.613281 -1.5625 C -5.011719 -1.824219 -5.3125 -2.148438 -5.511719 -2.53125 C -5.703125 -2.914063 -5.800781 -3.3125 -5.804688 -3.734375 C -5.800781 -4.464844 -5.53125 -5.089844 -4.996094 -5.605469 C -4.453125 -6.117188 -3.757813 -6.375 -2.90625 -6.378906 C -2.34375 -6.375 -1.820313 -6.253906 -1.339844 -6.015625 C -0.855469 -5.769531 -0.484375 -5.4375 -0.230469 -5.015625 C 0.0273438 -4.59375 0.152344 -4.113281 0.152344 -3.578125 C 0.152344 -2.660156 -0.183594 -1.914063 -0.855469 -1.335938 C -1.527344 -0.757813 -2.636719 -0.46875 -4.1875 -0.46875 C -5.914063 -0.46875 -7.171875 -0.789063 -7.960938 -1.429688 C -8.640625 -1.984375 -8.980469 -2.734375 -8.984375 -3.679688 C -8.980469 -4.382813 -8.785156 -4.957031 -8.390625 -5.410156 C -7.996094 -5.855469 -7.449219 -6.125 -6.757813 -6.21875 Z M -2.898438 -1.734375 C -2.519531 -1.734375 -2.15625 -1.8125 -1.8125 -1.972656 C -1.460938 -2.132813 -1.199219 -2.359375 -1.019531 -2.648438 C -0.839844 -2.9375 -0.75 -3.238281 -0.75 -3.558594 C -0.75 -4.019531 -0.9375 -4.417969 -1.3125 -4.753906 C -1.6875 -5.082031 -2.195313 -5.25 -2.839844 -5.253906 C -3.453125 -5.25 -3.941406 -5.085938 -4.300781 -4.757813 C -4.65625 -4.429688 -4.832031 -4.015625 -4.835938 -3.515625 C -4.832031 -3.015625 -4.65625 -2.59375 -4.300781 -2.25 C -3.941406 -1.90625 -3.472656 -1.734375 -2.898438 -1.734375 Z M -2.898438 -1.734375 "/>
</g>
<g overflow="visible" id="glyph1-3">
<path style="stroke:none;" d="M -4.851563 -2.210938 C -5.015625 -1.75 -5.253906 -1.414063 -5.566406 -1.195313 C -5.875 -0.976563 -6.242188 -0.867188 -6.675781 -0.867188 C -7.324219 -0.867188 -7.871094 -1.097656 -8.316406 -1.566406 C -8.757813 -2.03125 -8.980469 -2.65625 -8.984375 -3.4375 C -8.980469 -4.214844 -8.753906 -4.84375 -8.304688 -5.320313 C -7.847656 -5.796875 -7.296875 -6.035156 -6.648438 -6.035156 C -6.230469 -6.035156 -5.867188 -5.925781 -5.5625 -5.707031 C -5.25 -5.488281 -5.015625 -5.15625 -4.851563 -4.71875 C -4.671875 -5.265625 -4.382813 -5.683594 -3.984375 -5.972656 C -3.585938 -6.253906 -3.109375 -6.398438 -2.558594 -6.402344 C -1.789063 -6.398438 -1.144531 -6.128906 -0.628906 -5.589844 C -0.105469 -5.046875 0.152344 -4.332031 0.152344 -3.453125 C 0.152344 -2.566406 -0.105469 -1.855469 -0.628906 -1.316406 C -1.148438 -0.773438 -1.800781 -0.503906 -2.585938 -0.507813 C -3.164063 -0.503906 -3.652344 -0.652344 -4.050781 -0.949219 C -4.441406 -1.242188 -4.710938 -1.660156 -4.851563 -2.210938 Z M -6.714844 -1.988281 C -6.289063 -1.984375 -5.941406 -2.121094 -5.675781 -2.398438 C -5.40625 -2.667969 -5.273438 -3.023438 -5.273438 -3.460938 C -5.273438 -3.878906 -5.40625 -4.226563 -5.671875 -4.5 C -5.9375 -4.769531 -6.261719 -4.902344 -6.652344 -4.90625 C -7.050781 -4.902344 -7.390625 -4.765625 -7.667969 -4.488281 C -7.941406 -4.207031 -8.078125 -3.859375 -8.082031 -3.449219 C -8.078125 -3.027344 -7.945313 -2.679688 -7.675781 -2.402344 C -7.40625 -2.125 -7.085938 -1.984375 -6.714844 -1.988281 Z M -2.582031 -1.636719 C -2.265625 -1.632813 -1.960938 -1.707031 -1.671875 -1.859375 C -1.375 -2.003906 -1.148438 -2.226563 -0.992188 -2.519531 C -0.828125 -2.8125 -0.75 -3.128906 -0.75 -3.46875 C -0.75 -3.992188 -0.917969 -4.421875 -1.257813 -4.765625 C -1.59375 -5.105469 -2.023438 -5.277344 -2.546875 -5.28125 C -3.074219 -5.277344 -3.511719 -5.101563 -3.855469 -4.75 C -4.199219 -4.394531 -4.371094 -3.953125 -4.375 -3.429688 C -4.371094 -2.910156 -4.199219 -2.484375 -3.863281 -2.144531 C -3.519531 -1.804688 -3.09375 -1.632813 -2.582031 -1.636719 Z M -2.582031 -1.636719 "/>
</g>
<g overflow="visible" id="glyph1-4">
<path style="stroke:none;" d="M 0 -4.65625 L 0 -3.558594 L -7 -3.558594 C -6.746094 -3.289063 -6.492188 -2.941406 -6.242188 -2.515625 C -5.988281 -2.085938 -5.800781 -1.703125 -5.675781 -1.359375 L -6.738281 -1.359375 C -7.027344 -1.972656 -7.375 -2.507813 -7.789063 -2.972656 C -8.195313 -3.429688 -8.59375 -3.757813 -8.984375 -3.949219 L -8.984375 -4.65625 Z M 0 -4.65625 "/>
</g>
<g overflow="visible" id="glyph1-5"> <path style="stroke:none;" d="M -1.054688 -6.292969 L 0 -6.292969 L 0 -0.378906 C -0.265625 -0.367188 -0.519531 -0.410156 -0.761719 -0.507813 C -1.164063 -0.65625 -1.558594 -0.898438 -1.953125 -1.230469 C -2.339844 -1.558594 -2.792969 -2.035156 -3.308594 -2.667969 C -4.101563 -3.636719 -4.734375 -4.292969 -5.203125 -4.636719 C -5.667969 -4.976563 -6.105469 -5.148438 -6.523438 -5.152344 C -6.957031 -5.148438 -7.324219 -4.992188 -7.625 -4.683594 C -7.921875 -4.371094 -8.074219 -3.96875 -8.074219 -3.46875 C -8.074219 -2.9375 -7.914063 -2.511719 -7.597656 -2.195313 C -7.277344 -1.878906 -6.839844 -1.71875 -6.28125 -1.714844 L -6.398438 -0.585938 C -7.238281 -0.664063 -7.878906 -0.953125 -8.320313 -1.457031 C -8.761719 -1.960938 -8.980469 -2.640625 -8.984375 -3.492188 C -8.980469 -4.347656 -8.742188 -5.023438 -8.269531 -5.527344 C -7.789063 -6.027344 -7.199219 -6.28125 -6.5 -6.28125 C -6.140625 -6.28125 -5.789063 -6.207031 -5.445313 -6.058594 C -5.09375 -5.910156 -4.730469 -5.664063 -4.351563 -5.328125 C -3.964844 -4.984375 -3.441406 -4.421875 -2.777344 -3.636719 C -2.222656 -2.976563 -1.84375 -2.554688 -1.648438 -2.367188 C -1.449219 -2.179688 -1.253906 -2.023438 -1.054688 -1.90625 Z M -1.054688 -6.292969 "/>
</g>
<g overflow="visible" id="glyph1-6">
<path style="stroke:none;" d="M 0 -4.039063 L -2.140625 -4.039063 L -2.140625 -0.160156 L -3.148438 -0.160156 L -8.949219 -4.242188 L -8.949219 -5.140625 L -3.148438 -5.140625 L -3.148438 -6.347656 L -2.140625 -6.347656 L -2.140625 -5.140625 L 0 -5.140625 Z M -3.148438 -4.039063 L -7.183594 -4.039063 L -3.148438 -1.238281 Z M -3.148438 -4.039063 "/>
</g>
</g>
<clipPath id="clip1">
<path d="M 59.039063 59.039063 L 402.757813 59.039063 L 402.757813 359.558594 L 59.039063 359.558594 Z M 59.039063 59.039063 "/>
</clipPath>
<clipPath id="clip2">
<path d="M 59.039063 59.039063 L 402.757813 59.039063 L 402.757813 359.558594 L 59.039063 359.558594 Z M 59.039063 59.039063 "/>
</clipPath>
</defs>
<g id="surface34">
<g clip-path="url(#clip1)" clip-rule="nonzero">
<path style="fill:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke:rgb(0%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M 233.601563 208.800781 C 233.601563 213.066406 227.199219 213.066406 227.199219 208.800781 C 227.199219 204.535156 233.601563 204.535156 233.601563 208.800781 "/>
</g>
<path style="fill:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke:rgb(0%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M 71.734375 358.558594 L 389.066406 358.558594 "/>
<path style="fill:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke:rgb(0%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M 71.734375 358.558594 L 71.734375 365.761719 "/>
<path style="fill:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke:rgb(0%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M 151.066406 358.558594 L 151.066406 365.761719 "/>
<path style="fill:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke:rgb(0%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M 230.398438 358.558594 L 230.398438 365.761719 "/>
<path style="fill:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke:rgb(0%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M 309.734375 358.558594 L 309.734375 365.761719 "/>
<path style="fill:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke:rgb(0%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M 389.066406 358.558594 L 389.066406 365.761719 "/>
<g style="fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;">
<use xlink:href="#glyph0-0" x="63.046875" y="385.921875"/>
<use xlink:href="#glyph0-1" x="69.998779" y="385.921875"/>
<use xlink:href="#glyph0-2" x="73.47168" y="385.921875"/>
</g>
<g style="fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;">
<use xlink:href="#glyph0-0" x="142.378906" y="385.921875"/>
<use xlink:href="#glyph0-1" x="149.330811" y="385.921875"/>
<use xlink:href="#glyph0-3" x="152.803711" y="385.921875"/>
</g>
<g style="fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;">
<use xlink:href="#glyph0-4" x="221.710938" y="385.921875"/>
<use xlink:href="#glyph0-1" x="228.662842" y="385.921875"/>
<use xlink:href="#glyph0-0" x="232.135742" y="385.921875"/>
</g>
<g style="fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;">
<use xlink:href="#glyph0-4" x="301.046875" y="385.921875"/>
<use xlink:href="#glyph0-1" x="307.998779" y="385.921875"/>
<use xlink:href="#glyph0-5" x="311.47168" y="385.921875"/>
</g>
<g style="fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;">
<use xlink:href="#glyph0-4" x="380.378906" y="385.921875"/>
<use xlink:href="#glyph0-1" x="387.330811" y="385.921875"/>
<use xlink:href="#glyph0-6" x="390.803711" y="385.921875"/>
</g>
<path style="fill:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke:rgb(0%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M 59.039063 347.464844 L 59.039063 70.132813 "/>
<path style="fill:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke:rgb(0%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M 59.039063 347.464844 L 51.839844 347.464844 "/>
<path style="fill:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke:rgb(0%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M 59.039063 278.132813 L 51.839844 278.132813 "/>
<path style="fill:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke:rgb(0%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M 59.039063 208.800781 L 51.839844 208.800781 "/>
<path style="fill:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke:rgb(0%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M 59.039063 139.464844 L 51.839844 139.464844 "/>
<path style="fill:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke:rgb(0%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M 59.039063 70.132813 L 51.839844 70.132813 "/>
<g style="fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;">
<use xlink:href="#glyph1-0" x="43.199219" y="356.152344"/>
<use xlink:href="#glyph1-1" x="43.199219" y="349.200439"/>
<use xlink:href="#glyph1-2" x="43.199219" y="345.727539"/>
</g>
<g style="fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;">
<use xlink:href="#glyph1-0" x="43.199219" y="286.820313"/>
<use xlink:href="#glyph1-1" x="43.199219" y="279.868408"/>
<use xlink:href="#glyph1-3" x="43.199219" y="276.395508"/>
</g>
<g style="fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;">
<use xlink:href="#glyph1-4" x="43.199219" y="217.488281"/>
<use xlink:href="#glyph1-1" x="43.199219" y="210.536377"/>
<use xlink:href="#glyph1-0" x="43.199219" y="207.063477"/>
</g>
<g style="fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;">
<use xlink:href="#glyph1-4" x="43.199219" y="148.152344"/>
<use xlink:href="#glyph1-1" x="43.199219" y="141.200439"/>
<use xlink:href="#glyph1-5" x="43.199219" y="137.727539"/>
</g>
<g style="fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;">
<use xlink:href="#glyph1-4" x="43.199219" y="78.820313"/>
<use xlink:href="#glyph1-1" x="43.199219" y="71.868408"/>
<use xlink:href="#glyph1-6" x="43.199219" y="68.395508"/>
</g>
<path style="fill:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke:rgb(0%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M 59.039063 358.558594 L 401.761719 358.558594 L 401.761719
> 59.039063 L 59.039063 59.039063 L 59.039063 358.558594 "/>
<g style="fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;">
<use xlink:href="#glyph0-7" x="215.109375" y="414.71875"/>
<use xlink:href="#glyph0-8" x="218.582275" y="414.71875"/>
<use xlink:href="#glyph0-9" x="225.53418" y="414.71875"/>
<use xlink:href="#glyph0-10" x="232.486084" y="414.71875"/>
<use xlink:href="#glyph0-11" x="239.437988" y="414.71875"/>
</g>
<g style="fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;">
<use xlink:href="#glyph1-4" x="14.398438" y="212.277344"/>
</g>
<g clip-path="url(#clip2)" clip-rule="nonzero">
<path style="fill:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke:rgb(0%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:0.0117647;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M 59.039063 358.558594 L 93.3125 328.609375 "/>
<path style="fill:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke:rgb(100%,100%,100%);stroke-opacity:0.0117647;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M 59.039063 358.558594 L 93.3125 328.609375 "/>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Output (with Explorer plugin based on Qt):

[image: Snapshot in Explorer with Svg preview]

(Before modification, I just saw the axes without numbers as described by OP.)

Comment: Amazing ! So simple and yet I could have kept digging for days without coming up with that.
Seems to work fine. Thank you !

Comment: @AndéolEvain That's because I've the strange hobby to do my Qt SVG artwork in Notepad++ only. (I once tried Inkscape but I didn't like all the needless attributes with default values.) The `<symbol>` was the only one I couldn't remember and I thought a simple `<g>` should do as well. ;-)